# Which tensor should the metric raising or lowering?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

For something like $g^{ij} n_i h_{kj}$, how do I know which one should the metric operate on? $n_i$ or $h_{kj}$? The results could be $n^j h_{kj}$ or $n_i h^i_{k}$, which are different.

The question also appears when encountering partial derivatives too, like $g_{ij}\partial_i h^i$

Comment: *The results could be $n^j h_{kj}$ or $n_i h^i_{k}$, which are different.* Why do you think those are different?

Comment: What I was caring is the notation. Do you mean both give one-form as results so they have the same physical meaning?

Comment: When you studied Special Relativity, did you understand that $a^\mu b_\mu$ and $a_\mu b^\mu$ are the same contraction $a\cdot b$?

Comment: I thought that case is different from this one cuz $g_{\mu \nu} a^\mu b^\nu$, no matter how I operate, it still gives me a vector and an one-form. While this case gives vector with (0 2) tensor and one-form with (1 1) tensor. Now I see summing up gives same h_k, thanks!

Comment: But what about the partial derivative case? For example, consider $\partial_i \partial_j h^i$, I could think of $\Box h^i$ and $\partial_i \partial_j h_j$. It seems to me that they are not the same.

Comment: $\square h^i$ is $\partial_j \partial^ j h^i$. This is a totally different contraction, where the two derivatives are being contracted with each other, and neither with $h$. It is very important to notice what is being contracted with what.

Comment: @G.Smith, in that case, since two expressions are different, which one should the metric act on? One contracts with another derivative and one contracts with h. Indeed, I have never seen $\partial_i \partial^j h_j$, does it mean we should always contract the derivatives?

Comment: Sorry, your questions aren’t making sense to me. I am unable to understand what is confusing you. No, you do not “always contract the derivatives”.

Comment: The expression $g_{ij}\partial_i h^i$ in your question does not even make sense. You cannot have three $i$’s in one term.

Comment: I see. I forgot the rule of having at most two i. That made me in a wrong way.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your comments a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two expressions are equivalent. When contracting tensor indices, it doesn’t matter which one is up and which is down. So it doesn’t matter which one you contact with the (inverse) metric first.